# ggvis side-by-side barchart grouped by second variable

Tags: r, bar-chart, ggvis

I am in process of migrating from Excel to ggvis for data analysis. For a typical grouped bar chart with two variables, however I have difficulty to **plot** **bar chart side-by-side instead of stacked**.

The following data has four steps A, B, C, D with "ratio" data from two features cc, ca. My attempt is to plot the ratio from cc and ca features side-by-side. However, the default plot with stack the two data together. Check the ggvis vignetts has an option to set stack =FALSE. But it would overlap the other feature.

**Is there an option in ggvis to do things like "geom_bar(position="dodge")" in ggplot?**

```
library(ggvis)
steps <-c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D")
ratio <-c(1.1,1.5,1.7,1.4,1.5,1.7,1.4,1.9)
feature <-c("cc","cc","cc","cc","ca","ca","ca","ca")
shrink <- data.frame(steps,ratio,feature)
shrink %>% ggvis(x= ~steps, y= ~ratio, fill = ~feature) %>% layer_bars()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to do this yet.  But a work around is to explicitly define your x axis as a combination of your x and fill variables:

```
library(ggivs)
library(dplyr)

steps <-c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D")
ratio <-c(1.1,1.5,1.7,1.4,1.5,1.7,1.4,1.9)
feature <-c("cc","cc","cc","cc","ca","ca","ca","ca")
shrink <- data.frame(steps,ratio,feature)


shrink %>% 
   mutate(steps_feature = factor(paste(steps, feature))) %>%
   ggvis(x= ~steps_feature, y= ~ratio, fill = ~feature) %>% 
   layer_bars(stack = FALSE)
```

Not entirely satisfactory - you'd want to control the gaps between the bars, and maybe change the labels - but in the right direction.  I don't much like these plots anyway, I find them visually confusing, even though they are one of the most common plots around.
[image]

I know it's not what you asked, and it takes some users a time to get used to them, but I much prefer a scatter plot with this sort of data:

```
library(tidyr)
shrink %>%
   spread(feature, ratio) %>%
   ggvis(x = ~ca, y = ~cc, text := ~steps) %>%
   layer_text(fontSize := 35)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter for the work around codes. It is one of most common Bar chart that I wish ggvis would have an option later.

Comment: Any updates to this answer? The feature is still not available?

Comment: I'd second that question. I've been searching the documentation, but haven't been able to find any updates. 

I don't disagree they're confusing, but "the most common plots around" tends to get requested the most, too (sadly).